# Multiple Comparison / Assignment Operators on the Same Line in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function test(input){
   var value = input != 1;
}
```

In the above, what is the line inside of the function doing and how does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First it's doing the comparison `input != 1`, and then assigning the result of that (which will be `true` or `false`) the variable `value`. The `!=` is a [comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.2), the `=` is an [assignment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1).

This is exactly the same as any other assignment: The right-hand side is evaluated, and assigned to the left-hand side.

Answer (score 2):

See [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

`!=` has a precedence of 9 and `=` has a precedence of 17.

Therefore it evaluates `input != 1` and then assigns the result to `value`.